# Which is the largest/longest cave in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just read [this essay](http://stilldrinking.org/acceptable-losses) that says there's a cave that takes over 7 hours to "thoroughly" explore. Which cave is the author referring to?

> There's at least one cave that takes upwards of seven hours to thoroughly explore.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He is probably talking about [Blackreach](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Blackreach).

[image: Blackreach]

As taken from [here](http://www.officialplaystationmagazine.co.uk/2011/11/24/10-places-you-must-visit-in-skyrim/5/#gallery-top):

You gain access to Blackreach through the ancient Dwemer ruins of Alftand. The quest Elder Knowledge will take you there, and it’s the most bizarre, fascinating place in Skyrim. Here you’ll find the ruins of an **immense** Dwemer city, weird jellyfish-like glowing plants, and one of the game’s rarest items, **Crimson Nirnroot**. Picking one of these will start a quest, A Return To Your Roots, but watch out for the Falmer, Spheres, Wisps and Chaurus that dwell there.

[image: Blackreach 2]

Comment: Man I love that place.  When I first went there I couldn't believe it.  There's nothing else like it in the game.

Comment: Does Blackreach count as a cave? I always thought of it as an underground city. You can read into the lore of Blackreach and it sounds more of an ancient city than a cave.

Comment: Argh, Chaurus! Why'd you have to remind me of them?

Comment: @ChaseC I think it once was a magnificent city, yet it was swallowed by nature, hence becoming a "cave".

Comment: @Alex good times! haha